# Why does Socket not connect to the Host? Shows socketdidopen Not Called

Tags: sockets, swift

I used socketRocket framework to connect to my host in swift,

```
   var urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "ws://ipaddress:port")!);
   self.socket = SRWebSocket(URLRequest:urlRequest)

    self.socket?.delegate=self

    self.socket?.open()
```

the method webSocketDidOpen not call and after so many times method

```
   func webSocket(webSocket :SRWebSocket , didFailWithError error : NSError?){

    println("error")

}
```

called and the error is 'Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57',what should I have to do? Is the code run on simulator or I have to run it on the device?

Comment: Have you verified that your host web socket implentation is working at the URL you are using?

Comment: how can I understand this?

Answer (score 0):

This error means, that the host could not be found. You have to edit this url to your url and port:

For example:

```
var urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com:80")!)
```

At the moment you use an `NSURL` with this address: `"ws://ipaddress:port"` which isn't valid at all. So try it with a valid address like the one in my example and it should work.

Comment: I want plain socket not websocket,is this a right way?

Comment: No because that way you will get a websocket.